# Use of #if defined in C++ to select a Qt Kit

Tags: c++, qt

Similarly to the directive:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
....
#else
...
#endif
```

used to switch from something for Linux to something for other O.S., how can I set in C++ to switch from a Kit for Embedded System to a Kit for Desktop?
    #if defined(...what instruction...)
?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a define that every embedded system will have (I doubt there is one). However, you could always use your own defines like:

```
#define __IS_EMBEDDED__
```

or

```
#define __IS_DESKTOP__
```

and then check those at the appropriate places:

```
#if defined(__IS_EMBEDDED__)
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Depending on the system you build your software for, you can activate the appropriate defines. An elegant method to achieve this would be to pass the defines as compiler flags as suggested in the comment by @Murphy.

Comment: If you pass the define as compiler flag you'll be able to control the build from within the appropriate makefile.

Comment: @Murphy - Exactly this! simple than ever. Sometimes solution is at yuor fingertips...